# My first Django App - don't know how to create a homepage

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-3.1

I have been learning python for some time now and I want to make one of my small programs available to more people.
I am learning how to make URLs for my project now and I cannot create a URL for a homepage. As I found in one of the courses for older django version, you should create a function in your urls.py file that looks like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('this is the test homepage')
```

and pair it with some lines in views.py:

```
path('^$', views.home)
```

This doesn't work for me. I also tried to create a path like this:

```
 path('/', views.home)
```

Please, help or direct me to up to date guides for django 3.1.1.

EDIT in response to @pygeek's request:

the content of my urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about/', views.about),
    path('/', views.home)
]
```

the contents of my apps array in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

And the project tree:

```
.
└── RemoveBigFile
    ├── RBF1module
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── RemoveBigFile
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── views.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── asgi.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── RemoveBigFile.sublime-project
    ├── RemoveBigFile.sublime-workspace
    ├── db.sqlite3
    └── manage.py
```

Comment: Keep the original urls reflex expression, that was correct. Please share your directory structure and your full urls.py as well as apps array in settings.py

Comment: The directory structure is:
__init__.py
__pycahce__
asgi.py
settings.py
urls.py
views.py
wsgi.py

I will share the rest by editing my main post, since I don't know how to add code in comments yet :P

@pygeek

Comment: no, I mean whole project directory tree—how your project is organized.

Comment: @pygeek
Well I used a few video explainers and it might be a bit messed up, but I also launched about section and it works well. So the project look like this:

trydjango/src/ProjectDirectory

and in ProjectDirectory I have:
db.sqlite3
manage.py
Module1 (that's an app folder)
ProjectFolder (that's a project created using django)
Project.sublime-project
Project.sublime-workspace

I don't know the sense of most of these things, but the guy running the tutorial asked to create them. Maybe later he will use them..

Comment: do this, install tree then run it on your projects directory and paste that in your question. Also, you don’t need a vid tutorial the Django tutorial is very good (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/)

Comment: What is a tree and where do I install it from, @pygeek?

Comment: if you have a Mac, install brew (search on google) then brew install tree. Tree a command line tool used to print directory structure to console.

Comment: @pygeek - I edit my main post again. Tree to long for the comments section

Comment: update the question with output from tree

Comment: Ye, did this, @pygeek

Comment: ok, you have two views.py, which one did you update?

Comment: What do you see when you navigate to / in your browser?

Comment: I updated the views.py outside of __pycache__ inside the main project folder, @pygeek

Comment: And this is the info I get from the homepage when I try to view it (after changing URL to ^$):
Page not found (404)
Using the URLconf defined in RemoveBigFile.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
about/
^$
The empty path didn't match any of these.
@pygeek

Comment: Ok, Update installed apps list to include “RemoveBigFile”.

Comment: How do I format the comand to add this app? Just write down the directory's name? Or do I have to go with this django.contrib things before it, @pygeek?

Comment: Allright, @pygeek, thanks for all the inspiration and links :) I found the solution myself thanks to this discussion. It's here in one of the sample codes:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
In 3.1. Mainpage is indicated just by '' :) Now it works fine.

Comment: No problem. If my answer was accurate please mark it answer, otherwise add and accept your own answer to the question for reference.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Glad you got it working. Def. follow the tutorial much better than anything else I’ve come across for getting started with Django.

Comment: I can accept the answer after 2 days. I summarized our discussion in it. Thanks for your contribution yet again. Can't upvote you, @pygeek since I have to less reputation and I would gladly do if I could :/

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3.1. django uses an empty quote

```
''
```

for homepage instead of regex

```
^$
```

or slash

```
/
```

Thanks to @pygeek's contribution my code looks like this in urls.py:

```
path('', views.home),
```

and works just fine. I found the response in sample codes in the following link:
docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls

Answer (score 1):

You can use HttpResponse but I find it is better to render the page. Here is a quick sample.

```py
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from appname import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index')
]
```

```py
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
   return render(request, 'index.html')
```

This view will be triggered when an empty url path is requested. In the development environment this would be: http://localhost:8000/
This assumes you have also created a templates directory in your project root. You can verify this in settings.py.

```py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Take note of the 'DIRS' which is pointing to the base directory, then looking for a directory called 'templates'. This directory will be the home of the templates rendered when the view is called. In views.py notice 'index.html' this is the template the view will render when the function is called.

Another important point. For each app you create with `python manage.py startapp appname` you should create a python file called `urls.py` within that app directory. In order for this to work you should modify your main `urls.py` to look something like this:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('appname.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: I will get to templates and rendering later. When I learn that I will try this method. Thank you, @nightwolfgroup. For now I am looking for a solution that uses easier commands. I am quite new to django and I want to understand what I am doing.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the original question

Comment: @pygeek render_to_response was removed in Django 3.0. But I agree, class based views are great when necessary.